# Get Id from parent

Tags: jquery, html, dom-traversal

```
<div rownumber="0" messageid="112" class="post" style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
    <div class="post_body">hey hey hey</div>
    <div class="post_info" style="top: 0px;">
        <ul>
            <li class="vote"><a href="#">vote up</a></li>
            <li class="flag"><a href="#">flag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the 'vote up' or 'flag' `href` links, I want to be able to grab the `messageId` from the main containing `div` element. How would I do that?

Comment: Define "grab". What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( 'li.vote a, li.flag a' ).click( function( e )
{
    var msgId = $( this ).closest( 'div.post' ).attr( 'messageid' );

    e.preventDefault();
} );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/jQuGP/4/

Using a `data-` attribute and the jQuery `.data()` method would be best, though, as it would comply more closely with HTML standards: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/jQuGP/5/

Comment: Set the handler on the `a`, surely.

Comment: Sure. Was just giving the basic idea, but I see your point and corrected it.

Comment: `.closest()` would be better suited for this job.

Comment: I'd also limit the selector `$(this).parents('div.post')` to just one node. ["the elements are returned in order from the closest parent to the outer ones."](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) and you never know!

Comment: @bazmegakapa How so? I understand what `.closest()` is for, and don't understand why it would be "better suited". Unless you're concerned about the markup structure changing such that `div.post` is no longer the parent.

Comment: @JAAulde Check out the manual page on `.closest()`. There is a little section describing the difference between that and `.parents()`.

Comment: @bazmegakapa - fine, will do.  But on a site like SO, the purpose of which is learning, it's not cool to make unsubstantiated claims of something being "better." Give a small explanation, or a link to the doc section you're talking about. I rock with jQ, but have lots of stuff to learn--I'd like to do just that.

Comment: @bazmegakapa - having read the simple explanation, I agree that `.closest()` is somewhat better for this purpose. Answered modified accordingly.

Comment: @JAAulde I haven't made unsubstatiated claims. I've given an explanation in my answer, I just did want to repeat myself. You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), I can't link to the table directly, but you will see it. Besides, we're all learners here even if we try to teach.

Comment: @JAAulde All fine, I did not mean to insult. I'm giving you my upvote of course now.

Comment: @ bazmegakapa, I did not mean to insult either.  By unsubstantiated, I mean in the context of your comment you offered no reasoning. When I make comments like the one you made, I try to say something like, "as I stated in my answer," to give contextual reasoning without repeating myself. Peace :)

Comment: "`.closest()` would be better suited for this job" seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal It's clear that someone thinks it's better. I didn't wonder *if* he thought it was better, but *why*. It's not contextually clear *why* it's better, thus my query (pun intended). Anyway, moving on now--having a bad day and it shows. :P

Answer (score 3):

Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.post a').click( function() {
    var msgId = $(this).closest('.post').attr('messageid');
});
```

Also, you should use the `data-` prefix on custom attributes to ensure conformity with web standards.

Comment: You'd want the click even on the `a` tag, not the li.  Also, +1 for the `data-` prefix.

Comment: @kyle, thanks yes i was just correcting that as you commented! :) Although actually I think the use of `<a>` here is incorrect anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go up in the tree until a match is found. It is better suited here than `.parents()` which will filter all the parents of the link (which can be a lot of elements in a bigger markup), while `.closest()` stops when a match is found.

```
$('li.vote a, li.flag a').click(function () {
    var id=$(this).closest('div.post').attr('messageid');
});
```

---

**Another important thing:**

For storing arbitrary data on HTML elements, you should use **the `data-` attributes** (which were introduced in the HTML5 standard).

So in your example the HTML would be:

```
<div data-rownumber="0" data-messageid="112" class="post"...
```

Another advantage (besides a valid HTML document) is that you can simply get these data with **the jQuery `.data()` function**:

```
var id=$(this).closest('div.post').data('messageid');
```

[jsFiddle Demo with `data-` attributes](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/jkhGm/)

Comment: +1 extra educational info on data attrs is quite useful to the OP

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but something like this may work:

```
$(".vote a").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).parents(".post").attr("messageid");

    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you get around the problem by dynamically output an id on the `<a>` element that contains the message id?

something like

`<a href="#" id="message-123">`

Comment: I agree something like that would be useful, though you would have to be careful not to cause duplicate IDs in the document. You'd also have have to add something to parse the ID off the ID attr. Perhaps the `rel` attr would be handy to hold just the ID, avoiding the problem with ID duplication and parsing.

Comment: if not, try using `class`, then

Answer (score 0):

```
$( 'li.vote, li.flag' ).click(function() {
    var msgId = $(this).closest('[messageId]').attr('messageId');
)}
```